# android:layout_alignParentRight="true"doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, mobile, android-framelayout

I've got a `FrameLayout`in a `LinearLayout`and I want to position it to the right. Tried `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` but doesn't seem to work. Any ideas why? Please see my code below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_normal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/pb"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <CheckableImageButton
            android:id="@+id/conference_checkableimagebutton_lockstate"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/conference_checkableimagebutton_lockstate_src"
            android:cropToPadding="false"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
        android:id="@+id/conference_text_lockstate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gap_normal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gap_normal"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_normal"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/gap_large"
        android:text="Unlocked. When all participants have joined, lock the conference by tapping the padlock."
        app:typeface="roboto_condensed_regular" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:layout_alignParentRight=“true”doesn't work`, because your parent is a **LinearLayout**.   `alignParentRight` (as well as all the other **relative** attributes) only works in **RelativeLayouts**.

Comment: the problem is, I need the first Linear Layout, so is it someting I can do in this instance?

Comment: My answer is correct. If you want (you have to explain me why you say you "need") a LinearLayout, then you can't use the relative attributes. Simple.

Comment: `Any ideas why?` Yes. Answered.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 


<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/pb"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <CheckableImageButton
            android:id="@+id/conference_checkableimagebutton_lockstate"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/conference_checkableimagebutton_lockstate_src"
            android:cropToPadding="false"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
        android:id="@+id/conference_text_lockstate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gap_normal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gap_normal"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_normal"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/gap_large"
        android:text="Unlocked. When all participants have joined, lock the conference by tapping the padlock."
        app:typeface="roboto_condensed_regular" />





</RelativeLayout>
```